# Summernote set cursor at end of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr, summernote

I'm using Signalr with summernote. Every time a receive a text from the hub, or if I am writing, the cursor sets in the begining of the text. I've tried a few stackoverflow solutions but it does not work.

It works if I use a simple text area.

Any ideas on how to set the cursor at the end after calling  $('#Goal_Description').summernote("code", message);?

Thanks.